# In Java, is there such a thing as a "do when" loop?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Okay, it might be a noob question, but I couldnt find anything to help me. I am loading an BitMap on a ImageView as an Async task, in this class:

```
class MyNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView tIV;

public MyNetworkTask(ImageView iv){
    tIV = iv;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... urls) {

    Bitmap networkBitmap = null;

    URL networkUrl = urls[0]; //Load the first element
    try {
        networkBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                networkUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return networkBitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    tIV.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

And thats how I call it from my Activity:

```
new MyNetworkTask(myImageView).execute(photo_url);
```

But that is going to be async, right? Which means that if right after in my Activity I try to use the BitMap, it will be **null**.

Is there a loop like a "*do when??*" that waits for this BitMap, and than do something?

Or is there a way of handling a callback from that Async Class?

Comment: *is there a way of handling a callback from that Async Class* yes it's called a callback. If you google for 'android asynctask callback' you will get about 23563465467 results explaning how it works :-)

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns, I will take a look at this link :)

Comment: If you feel that the link answers your question, you can click the banner up top to accept it as a duplicate :-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of storing the bitmap so you can access it later you should create a `public Bitmap bitmap;` outside of your AsyncTask then populate it from your AsyncTask.

```
class MyNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView tIV;

public MyNetworkTask(ImageView iv){
    tIV = iv;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... urls) {

    Bitmap networkBitmap = null;

    URL networkUrl = urls[0]; //Load the first element
    try {
        networkBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                networkUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return networkBitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if(result != null){
        bitmap = result;
    }
    tIV.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern observer for that. Check out this link for the implementation http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean with "do when"?
I think of something like that:

```
do{
    networkBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            networkUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
}while(networkBitmap==null)
```

same works with a while loop:

```
while(networkBitmap==null){
    networkBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            networkUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
}
```

Comment: No that is not what he means

Comment: Although one is a pretest loop and one is a posttest loop

Comment: yeah, but he asked also for something like a "do when" loop, which basically is a while- or do-while-loop. i know, that there won't happen anything usefull in my loops, but with such loops he could anyhow try to get a bitmap, while it is null

Comment: Do note that "while" and "when" are very very different things, especially in programming

Comment: Thanks man, but it is not a do while, that I know how to do :) . I dont even know if there is such a thing as a "do when", thats why I asked. :)